# How can I make this to show everything on the menu instead of having to search?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make this to show everything on the "menu" without having to do a search every time?
Where it shows the whole list of everything on the menu and allows the users to easily add order

[image: I got this off gitHub]

https://github.com/zaisahil/inventory

I found this from gitHub.  It's an Inventory Management System.  Thanks

Edit:

```
<?php ob_start();
$page_title = 'Add Order';
  require_once('includes/load.php');
  // Checking What level user has permission to view this page
   page_require_level(3);
?>
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['add_sale'])){
    $req_fields = array('s_id','quantity','price','total', 'date' );
    validate_fields($req_fields);
        if(empty($errors)){
          $p_id      = $db->escape((int)$_POST['s_id']);
          $s_qty     = $db->escape((int)$_POST['quantity']);
          $s_total   = $db->escape($_POST['total']);
          $date      = $db->escape($_POST['date']);
          $s_date    = make_date();

          $sql  = "INSERT INTO sales (";
          $sql .= " product_id,qty,price,date";
          $sql .= ") VALUES (";
          $sql .= "'{$p_id}','{$s_qty}','{$s_total}','{$s_date}'";
          $sql .= ")";

                if($db->query($sql)){
                  update_product_qty($s_qty,$p_id);
                  $session->msg('s',"Sale added. ");
                  redirect('add_sale.php', false);
                } else {
                  $session->msg('d',' Sorry failed to add!');
                  redirect('add_sale.php', false);
                }
        } else {
           $session->msg("d", $errors);
           redirect('add_sale.php',false);
        }
  }

?>
<?php include_once('layouts/header.php'); ?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <?php echo display_msg($msg); ?>
    <form method="post" action="ajax.php" autocomplete="off" id="sug-form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
            </span>
            <input type="text" id="sug_input" class="form-control" name="title"  placeholder="Search for menu items">
         </div>
         <div id="result" class="list-group"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <strong>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
          <span>Order Menu</span>
       </strong>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form method="post" action="add_sale.php">
         <table class="table table-bordered">
           <thead>
            <th> Item </th>
            <th> Price </th>
            <th> Qty </th>
            <th> Total </th>
            <th> Date</th>
            <th> Action</th>
           </thead>
             <tbody  id="product_info"> </tbody>
         </table>
       </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<?php include_once('layouts/footer.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Can you kindly copy the code where the data is being fetched to the table after querying. That would be a great help.

Comment: Yeah, np.  I tried and was going to but it was giving me an error saying the code is too long and that I needed to add more details.

Comment: Done.  I believe I added the correct code.

Comment: @JustCurious bump

Comment: I tried to setup this project in my system. (In add_sale.php) The product related info is fetched from ```ajax.php``` which then calls ```find_all_product_info_by_title()``` which is located in ```sql.php``` for fetching the data row-wise. You can change the code accordingly there to fetch all the data by changing sql to ```SELECT * FROM products ;```

Comment: Kindly check the answer, its working as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I add another fetch for action?  Like the same action that happens when I search, then click on the action of the result

Comment: As requested, I have added the add sales button and it stores the data in sales table of the db.Kindly check the code now.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all the products data without putting a title, Kindly change your table in `add_sales.php` to this.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
           <thead>
            <th> Item </th>
            <th> Price </th>
            <th> Qty </th>
            <th> Total </th>
            <th> Date</th>
            <th> Action</th>
           </thead>
             <tbody  id="product_info">
              <?php 
               $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
                 $result = $db->query($sql);
                  $results = $db->while_loop($result);               

                foreach ($results as $result){                
                  ?>
                      <tr>
                     <td><?= $result['name'] ?><input type="hidden" name="s_id" value=<?= $result['id'] ?> ></td>
                     <td><?= $result['sale_price'] ?> <input type="hidden" name="price" value = <?= $result['sale_price'] ?> ></td>
                      <td><?= $result['quantity'] ?><input type="hidden" name="quantity" value=<?= $result['quantity'] ?> > </td>
                      <td><?= $result['sale_price'] ?><input type="hidden" name="total" value=<?= $result['sale_price'] ?> ></td>
                      <td><?= $result['date'] ?><input type="hidden" name="date" value=<?= $result['date'] ?> ></td>
                      <td><button type="submit" name="add_sale" class="btn btn-primary">Add sale</button></td>
                      </tr> 
             <?php   } ?>
              </tbody>
         </table>
```

**Note:** You can change the value of the `<td> and value` according to your needs.
This will get the data in form of rows into your page. Obviously you can change the data you want according to your database names.
Hope it Helps. Cheers!!